# I am not sure what is wrong with my VLOOKUP equation

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup, spreadsheet

I'm pretty sure that my equation is correct and if not, I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Image linking to my sheets issue]

Comment: It seems you get the value of "Dan", but I also don't know why.

Comment: If the desired behaviour is to return the value in B5, try adding `FALSE` as a fourth parameter, but the text in the bottom right suggests that you should be looking elsewhere for your data, and if you do indeed want the value of B5 then you can simply use `=B5`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The third column should be equal to the 2nd column, but for some reason the ordering of the %s is messed up and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The ordering is not messed up: the issue is that your formula uses approximate search, while you need exact search, as JSheeran already mentioned. Just add `FALSE` as a last parameter and it will work.

Comment: In that case, just put `=B4` in C4 and fill down. But why do you want to duplicate the values in that column?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to learn how to use Index and Match formulas instead. For this example, it would be `=INDEX(A4:B8,MATCH(A5,A4:A8,0),2)`. Remember to lock the cells if you wish to drag it.

Answer (score 0):

use 4th parameter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5, A4:B8, 2, 0)
```